# Rest one month in a date golang

Tags: date, go, parsing

Im trying to rest a month in a date in golang i have this example for march an February:

```
date := time.Date(2023, time.March, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

then a make this:

```
period := date.AddDate(0, -1, -0)
```

but the program give me:

> original date: 2023-03-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
>
> date after rest: 2023-03-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

And I expect:

> 2023-02-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

at the same time I want that this rest work for every month dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `delivery.MonthlyPeriod.AddDate`?

Comment: Sorry that its date variable i edit my question

Comment: There is no February 31, so the date is normalized. "AddDate normalizes its result in the same way that Date does, so, for example, adding one month to October 31 yields December 1, the normalized form for November 31." https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.AddDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the automatically transform that comes with go annoys you, you could also take advantage of this.

The trick is how to get the number of days in the previous month.

```golang
// as there is no 0 day, it means the last day of the previous mouth
totDay := time.Date(y, m, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Day()
```

The complete code is as follows：

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func previousMouth(t time.Time) time.Time {
    y, m, d := t.Date()

    curTotDay := time.Date(y, m+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Day()
    totDay := time.Date(y, m, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Day()
    if d == curTotDay {
        d = totDay
    }

    return time.Date(y, m-1, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
}

func main() {
    date := time.Date(2023, time.March, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(previousMouth(date))
}
```

Run it online: [goplayground](https://go.dev/play/p/SHeFoLoW6SJ).

Comment: if you put time.February it gives you.28- Jan that is not correct

Comment: @FernandoGonzález Alright, I didn't realize the problem just now, I've changed the answer, the  code is even shorter.

Comment: Yup this is similar to my answer thanks so much for your time. Accept this.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you cannot go back exactly one month from 31 March. You would end up at 31 February, but that date doesn't exist and is normalised to 3 March.

You can go back to the last day of the previous month, but you would get the same result if you started at 28 March, 29 March, 30 March or 31 March.

But if that is what you want, you can go back (or forward) any number of months, while clipping the day to remain within the number of days in that month.

```
func firstDayOfMonth(date time.Time) time.Time {
    return date.AddDate(0, 0, -date.Day()+1)
}

func daysInMonth(date time.Time) int {
    return date.AddDate(0, 1, -date.Day()).Day()
}

func AddMonthsClipped(date time.Time, months int) time.Time {
    firstDate := firstDayOfMonth(date)
    firstAdded := firstDate.AddDate(0, months, 0)
    addDays, maxDays := date.Day(), daysInMonth(firstAdded)
    if addDays > maxDays {
        addDays = maxDays
    }
    return firstAdded.AddDate(0, 0, addDays-1)
}

func main() {
    date := time.Date(2023, time.March, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(AddMonthsClipped(date, -1))
}
```

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/JEihMdM0CHe

Comment: Same that the other answer if you put time.February,28 it gives as output 28-Jan

Comment: Yes, what else did you expect? 28 February minus one month is 28 January. No matter whether you clip or not. Just like 12 February minus one month is 12 January.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date := time.Date(2023, time.March, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    year, month, _ := date.Date()
    endOfLastMonth := time.Date(year, month, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, date.Location())
    fmt.Println("This month: ", date)
    fmt.Println("Lasth Month: ", endOfLastMonth)
}
```

Here the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/iTDFgtdOT9y
After working and working with the date, i made this. Thanks you all